# What is an easy way for finding C and N when proving the Big-Oh of an Algorithm?

Tags: big-o

I'm starting to learn about Big-Oh notation.

What is an easy way for finding C and N<sub>0</sub> for a given function?

Say, for example:

(n+1)<sup>5</sup>, or n<sup>5</sup>+5n<sup>4</sup>+10n<sup>2</sup>+5n+1

I know the formal definition for Big-Oh is:

> Let f(n) and g(n) be functions mapping
>   nonnegative integers to real numbers. 
>   We say that f(n) is O(g(n)) if there
>   is a real constant c > 0 and an
>   integer constant N<sub>0</sub> >= 1
>   such that f(n) <= cg(n) for every integer N > N<sub>0</sub>.

My question is, what is a good, sure-fire method for picking values for c and N<sub>0</sub>?

For the given polynomial above (n+1)<sup>5</sup>, I have to show that it is O(n<sup>5</sup>).  So, how should I pick my c and N<sub>0</sub> so that I can make the above definition true without guessing?

Comment: I think you want to add "for all n >= N0" to the end of your definition.

Comment: @Ambouroko, very true. Fixed it.

Answer (score 13):

You can pick a constant c by adding the coefficients of each term in your polynomial.  Since

| n<sup>5</sup> + 5n<sup>4</sup> + 0n<sup>3</sup> + 10n<sup>2</sup> + 5n<sup>1</sup> + 1n<sup>0</sup> | <= | n<sup>5</sup> + 5n<sup>5</sup> + 0n<sup>5</sup> + 10n<sup>5</sup> + 5n<sup>5</sup> + 1n<sup>5</sup> |

and you can simplify both sides to get

| n<sup>5</sup> + 5n<sup>4</sup> + 10n<sup>2</sup> + 5n + 1 | <= | 22n<sup>5</sup> |

So c = 22, and this will always hold true for any n >= 1.

It's almost always possible to find a lower c by raising N<sub>0</sub>, but this method works, and you can do it in your head.

(The absolute value operations around the polynomials are to account for negative coefficients.)

Comment: amazing explanation

Answer (score 3):

Usually the proof is done without picking concrete C and N<sub>0</sub>. Instead of proving f(n) < C * g(n) you prove that f(n) / g(n) < C.

For example, to prove n<sup>3</sup> + n is O(n<sup>3</sup>) you do the following:

(n<sup>3</sup> + n) / n<sup>3</sup> = 1 + (n / n<sup>3</sup>) = 1 + (1 / n<sup>2</sup>) < 2 for any n >= 1. Here you can pick any C >= 2 with N<sub>0</sub> = 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can check what the lim abs(f(n)/g(n)) is when n->+infitity and that would give you the constant (g(n) is n^5 in your example, f(n) is (n+1)^5).

Note that the meaning of Big-O for x->+infinity is that if f(x) = O(g(x)), then f(x) "grows no faster than g(x)", so you just need to prove that lim abs(f(x)/g(x)) exists and is less than +infinity.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend greatly on the function you are considering.  However, for a given class of functions, you may be able to come up with an algorithm.

For instance, polynomials:  if you set C to any value greater than the leading coefficient of the polynomial, then you can solve for N<sub>0</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

After you understand the magic there, you should also get that big-O is a **notation**.  It means that you *do not have to look for these coefficients in every problem you solve*, once you made sure you understood what's going on behind these letters.  You should just operate the symbols according to the *notaion*, according to its rules.

There's no easy generic rule to determine actual values of N and c.  You should recall your calculus knowledge to solve it.

The definition to big-O is entangled with [definition of the limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence).  It makes c satisfy:

c > lim |f(n)/g(n)|, given n approaches +infinity.

If the sequence is upper-bounded, it always has a limit.  If it's not, well, then f is not O(g).  After you have picked concrete c, you will have no problem finding appropriate N.